# Using flexbox, how does align-content:stretch work when combined with align-items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Been playing around with flexbox, and most of the configurations seem to be making sense. One that doesn't to me though is how if you set `align-content` to `stretch` (default option), and set `align-items: center, flex-end, or flex-start`, it does not stretch the rows, contrary to what I originally would have thought based on the pictures I have seen from the flexbox w3 site.

It instead gives you rows separated by a margin. I am curious why/how these margins are determined, and why the flex-items do not stretch across its flex-container?

Here is a JSBIN replicating the problem: http://jsbin.com/cehogay/edit?html,css,output

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 5px blue;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">22</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">6666666</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using flexbox, how does `align-content:stretch` work when combined with `align-items`?

When you are working with a single-line flex container (`flex-wrap: nowrap`), `align-content` has no effect. You can use `align-items` and `align-self` to position flex items.

When you are working with a multi-line flex container (`flex-wrap: wrap`), `align-content` goes into effect and can be used to pack flex lines in the same way `justify-content` works on the main axis.

> ...how if you set `align-content` to stretch (default option), and set `align-items: center`, `flex-end`, or `flex-start`, it does not stretch the rows.It instead gives you rows separated by a margin.

These are not margins. This is `align-content: stretch` at work. This setting is taking the length of the container's *cross-axis* (in this case, height), and distributing that space equally among each line.

Here's the spec definition of `stretch` for the `align-content` property:

> [***`stretch`***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> Lines stretch to take up the remaining space. If the leftover free-space is negative, this value is identical to `flex-start`. Otherwise, the free-space is split equally between all of the lines, increasing their cross size.

In other words, `align-content: stretch` on the cross axis is similar to `flex: 1` on the main axis.

If you switch from `align-content: stretch` to `align-content: flex-start`, those gaps are gone.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 5px blue;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">22</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">6666666</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>

</div>
```

> Why do the flex-items not stretch across its flex-container?

They do. In your demo, you're probably looking at the black borders. These borders don't represent the line. They represent the flex item.

Each line is exactly the same height because `align-content: stretch` has distributed the container space equally among each line. (The height of each row is determined by dividing the height of the container by the number of rows.)

When you use `align-items: flex-start` or `center` or `flex-end`, you are not changing the height of the line. You are re-positioning the flex item within that line. But if you switch to `align-items: stretch`, you'll close the gaps.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 5px blue;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">22</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">6666666</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>
  <div class="child">211212</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you look at the example, the lines do not stretch to take the available space (when align-items, and align-content is used), as there is empty space between the rows. Is there something about using align-items, or something about the wrapping that is nullifying the expected behavior (which is the lines should stretch, so there is no empty spaces)?

Comment: The lines *do* stretch to fill the row. You're looking at the borders. The borders don't represent the line. They represent the flex item.

Comment: Oh ok. So for the above example, when using `align-items`, you're indicating where you want the flex item on the particular row ("line"). In this case, `align-items:center` would go in the middle of the row. Whereas `align-content`, arranges the rows themselves?